# How does one match '[default]' in a Bash test using '=~'?

Tags: bash, shell

I was trying to match `[default]` in a bash test, but couldn't get it to work in a bash test.  In the following test...

```
$ [[ "[default]" =~ "${PATTERN}" ]]
```

...what is the value for `$PATTERN`?  I can solve the problem using grep instead, but the same pattern doesn't work in a `=~` test.

```
$ echo "[default]" | grep '\[[^\[]\+\]' # returns 0
$ [[ "[default]" =~ '\[[^\[]\+\]' ]]    # returns 1
```

Comment: Don't quote RHS of `=~`.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't know that.

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://ShellCheck.net) recognizes common problems including [this one](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2076)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use conditional expressions with `[[...]]` you don't need to escape regex:

```
[[ "[default]" =~ \[[^\[]+\] ]]
```

Comment: Could you please explain `\[[^\[]+\] ]]` this part? Will be grateful to you.

Comment: `[[...]]` has also been introduced to avoid regex escaping. The actual regex here is `\[[^\[]+\]` and the only needed escapes are `\[ \]`to distinguish the characters `[ ]` from a set structure. Do you need an explanation on what this regex does?

Answer (score 1):

```
PATTERN='\[default\]'
[[ "[default]" =~ ${PATTERN} ]] && echo okay
```

Output:

```
okay
```

Comment: Interesting.  It looks like my problem was the usage of quotes in the match.  This...  `[[ "[default]" =~ "${PATTERN}" ]] && echo okay` ...does not work.  Funky.